# Replace fail disk in ML350 G5 when system is running

Tags: raid

I have a RAID 1+0 consisting of 4x 146GB SAS disks on a Smart Array E200i.

One disk reports an error in event log:

> The Physical drive at Port 1I : Box 1 : Bay 2 is reporting S.M.A.R.T. errors.

Can I replace the failed disk when Windows Server 2003 is runnig?

Comment: If you have a spare bay you might consider adding a hot spare. You should also add alerting because the event log is *not* the first place you should learn about these issues. Check the controller manual, as many controllers are capable of sending alerts directly.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your RAID configuration.

If you have simple concat or simple stripe you will break volume.

Any mirrored configuration should be OK if just one disk fails.

RAID 1+0 (mirrored stripe) is also OK.

Answer (score 1):

Only if your disks are hot-pluggable. Check their specifications, if I remember correctly there are some not hot plug sas disks at HP.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have 432320-001 HP 146GB 2.5" SFF 3G Single Port SAS 10K RPM Hot Plug Hard Drive , so hot swap is available